# Do space suit designers exist?

Tags: spacex, nasa, design, spacesuits, boeing

I was just having a closer look at the new space-suits by SpaceX,
that were worn by NASA astronauts Bob Behnken and Doug Hurley (image below this question).

The design made me wonder about who may have designed these suits. And the people generally designing space-suits.

**Are there people whose only job is to design space suits** - Space suit designers? Or is it more of a thing a team of engineers and chemists does? Does this job exist at NASA, SpaceX or somewhere else - or not at all?

[image: SpaceX suits worn by Bob Behnken and Doug Hurley]

Comment: An engineer who took on the task of creating such space suit is by definition a space suit designer.

Comment: Interesting read related to this. The SpaceX suits pictured were actually designed by a movie costume designer (presumably with input from engineers): https://www.nytimes.com/2020/05/27/fashion/SpaceX-Dragon-Suits.html

Comment: NASA and Boeing also design new space suits so I've added their tags. Also related: [How many current or near-future pressure suits are there for use in space in total?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44834/12102)

Comment: @ChrisLoonam excellent reference, I think you could expand on that as an answer! I wanted to add the `space-art` tag but now there's no room :-)

Comment: @ChrisLoonam Hopefully the movie costume designer accepted the technical and physical limits to his freedom as an artist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, space suit designers exist. For example [Final Frontier Design](http://www.finalfrontierdesign.com/). Also you can see some pictures of their suits, some historic designs and designers themselves at [1](https://habr.com/ru/post/399631/), [2](https://habr.com/ru/post/379243/) (text in Russian).