# Is there a standard in spacesuit pressure testing protocol?

Tags: spacesuits

Following [Elon Musk](https://www.instagram.com/p/BYIPmEFAIIn/)'s and [SpaceX](https://www.reddit.com/r/Damnthatsinteresting/comments/4cgajk/spacex_suits_look_like_they_come_straight_from_a/)'s recent announcements of their spacesuits being tested to "[double vacuum pressure](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22770/what-does-double-vacuum-pressure-mean-in-space-suit-testing)", there's been some speculation on what this meant.

It got me wondering - do NASA, ESA, or other agencies have a standard test protocol? And could someone post a short description of it?

Comment: You're asking about ground tests, right?  Because there is a procedurally built in leak check after suit donning at the beginning of a spacewalk.

Comment: In an answer to this question https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13331/ , different operating pressures were given:  
"The Shuttle extravehicular mobility unit (EMU) has an operating pressure of 4.3 psi (30 kPa) and the Shuttle crew escape/launch/entry suits operates at a maximum of 3.5 psi (24 kPA). All Russian spacesuites, in comparison, operate at 5.8 psi (40kPa) to minimize or avoid decompression sickness or other risks."  
The pressures used for a test may be different too.

Comment: @organicmarble any and all would be good - especially if the ground test protocol(s) vary from pre-EVA checks in orbit

Comment: @uwe - but how are they tested. I'm assuming that failure pressure is a much higher rating than operating pressure (much like a submarine crush depth is below its operating maximum)

Comment: @HourusKol : But the safety factor used for the construction of a submarine might be much higher than that used for rockets and space equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Pressure tests are done on-orbit as part of the EMU CHECKOUT procedure, and during airlock depressurization prior to extra-vehicular activity (EVA).

During the EMU CHECKOUT procedure, the suit is pressurized to a delta pressure of 4.3 psia (its normal working pressure) and the suit caution and warning system monitors for a drop in pressure.

[image]

During the airlock depressurization prior to an EVA, the depressurization is halted when the airlock pressure reaches 5 psia, and again, the suit caution and warning system monitors for a drop in pressure.

[image]

Source: the shuttle-era EVA checklist is online [here](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/johnson/pdf/492872main_EVA_G_H_20.pdf).

Comment: But that is not a one time post manufacture pressure test. Doing a burst pressure test with a suit worth some million $ is a different thing. But during design some parts may have been tested destructively.

Comment: @Uwe Please notice that I asked the OP in a comment if they were interested in on-orbit tests, and they said yes.  So your comment is not constructive.

Comment: Excuse me, but the spacesuits tests to "double vacuum pressure" were ground tests and no in orbit tests. HorusKol was also interested in the ground test.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question; during the time between the two tests as the airlock pressure drops, the suit maintains a relatively constant delta pressure of 4.3 psia above the changing airlock pressure?

Comment: It's not a dumb question. The suit has a positive pressure relief valve that opens when the suit pressure is > 4.7 psi above ambient. So as the airlock pressure drops, this valve would be cracking and releasing gas from the suit to maintain that delta p.  When the suit is in a vacuum environment, this valve protects the suit from overpressurization.

Comment: @uhoh the ACES suit you were asking about in a different question also has a PPRV, I updated my answer there to talk about that.